# Get rid of unneeded DIVs in my if binding knockout

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I have an observable array with the following structure (where type can be only text or img):

```
ko.observableArray([{
    type: 'text',
    info: 'Hello'
},{
    type: 'img',
    info: 'http://cdn.zendesk.com/images/documentation/apps/logo-small.png'
}]);
```

Depending on the type I want to output either image or a bunch of text. So I am using the [if binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html). The [result looks the way I expected](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/AtSLE/), but the problem is in the underlying html:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: elements">
    <div data-bind="if: type == 'text'"><div data-bind="text: info">Hello</div>        </div>
    <div data-bind="if: type == 'img'"></div>  // Do not want it to be here

    <div data-bind="if: type == 'text'"></div> // Do not want it to be here
    <div data-bind="if: type == 'img'"><img data-bind="attr: { 'src': info}" src="http://cdn.zendesk.com/images/documentation/apps/logo-small.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

It keeps inserting empty `<divs>` if the if statement returns false.

When I tried to achieve what I wanted with [putting if and text binding in the same element](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/AtSLE/1/) I got the following error:

> Multiple bindings (if and text) are trying to control descendant
>   bindings of the same

How can I get rid of unneeded DIVs in my output html with the if binding?

If this is impossible to achieve with if-binding, is there a way to do this somehow else? Because if I will have not only type = 'text' or 'img' but also 'video' and a dozen of other things I will have all them empty sitting there just as an artifact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the extra divs you can use the [containerless control flow syntax](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html#note-using-if-without-a-container-element) of the `if` binding, which is based on comment tags:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: elements">
    <!-- ko if: type == 'text' -->
        <div data-bind="text: info"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: type == 'img' -->
        <img data-bind="attr: { 'src': info}" />
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gc4um/).

And the generated DOM will look like:

[image]

no extra divs only a few extra comments.

To get rid of these comments [you can use templates](http://jsfiddle.net/gc4um/1/).

Comment: Cool thank you. This is exactly what I wanted, because comments are not increasing the size of the DOM tree.

Comment: You can further clean up this approach using the `template` binding instead of the bunch of `if`s: http://jsfiddle.net/gc4um/1/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get rid of the extra divs.  I use the `if` binding do what you're doing on a regular basis.

The error you're getting simply indicates that you have competing bindings, which is expected with `if` and `visible` bindings.  Your `if` and `visible` bindings should always be one div higher, so to speak.

Below is a screenshot of my DOM using Google's dev tools.  The web application is actually running, and I use the `if` binding to reveal the view the user has chosen.

[image: Screenshot of my DOM using Google's dev tools--web application actually running]

The extra divs are simply an artifact of the `if` binding.

If you think about it, if the `if` binding were to disappear altogether, what would be left in the DOM to reconstitute it when the condition is satisfied and that portion of the view should be shown?

**UPDATE**

Upon reconsidering the `template` approach, you could push the logic into the viewmodel (vm), bind the `name` of the template to an observable on the vm, and then dynamically set the template based on that logic.  But, the templates themselves are going to hang around in the DOM.  So I don't think there's a net gain here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you sure that it is impossible to get rid of these extra diffs? May be with templating or other things, not necessarily with if binding.

Comment: @SalvadorDali You're welcome.  I can't speak to all methods in general as I have not actually strived to eliminate the empty divs.  But I would expect the logic to be the same: _Something_ has to remain to allow reconstitution based on the condition of the `if` binding, or the `template` binding, or binding "x" (call "x" what you will).

Comment: @nemesv The purpose of containerless binding is to introduce a binding where there can be no container, not to eliminate divs.  Indeed, why would anyone use container-ed binding for conditional binding?  Your answer begins, "If you don't need the extra divs..."  I don't think we ever _need_ the extra divs.